# np.select and str.extract if cond str.contains a certain regex is not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract the state from an address string and some of the addresses are canadian and some american. I think the regex is correct but it is creating an array of shape (29999,29999) and I'm not understanding why:

Here is a sample output of `data['Address']:

```
19                  6349 IN-45, Bloomington, IN 47403
20                                                  ~
21  370 Canyon Meadows Dr SE, Calgary, AB T2J 7C6,...
22                 3600 Genesee St, Buffalo, NY 14225
```

Here is my code:

```
data['state'] = np.select([data['Address'].str.contains(r',(\s.*\s[0-9])'),data['Address'].str.contains(r',(\s.*\s[A-Za-z][0-9])')],[data['Address'].str.extract(r',(\s.*\s[0-9])'),data['Address'].str.extract(r',(\s.*\s[A-Za-z][0-9])')])
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try:

```
data['State'] = data['Address'].str.extract(r',\s([^\s,]+)\s')
print(data)

# Output
                                              Address State
19                  6349 IN-45, Bloomington, IN 47403    IN
20                                                  ~   NaN
21  370 Canyon Meadows Dr SE, Calgary, AB T2J 7C6,...    AB
22                 3600 Genesee St, Buffalo, NY 14225    NY
```

---

**Old answer**

Is it what you expect:

```
data['State'] = data['Address'].str.extract(r',(\s.*\s(?:[A-Za-z])?[0-9])')
print(data)

# Output
                                              Address               State
19                  6349 IN-45, Bloomington, IN 47403   Bloomington, IN 4
20                                                  ~                 NaN
21  370 Canyon Meadows Dr SE, Calgary, AB T2J 7C6,...   Calgary, AB T2J 7
22                 3600 Genesee St, Buffalo, NY 14225       Buffalo, NY 1
```

I combine your choice list:

```
r',(\s.*\s[0-9])'
r',(\s.*\s[A-Za-z][0-9])'
```

into a single expression:

```
r'(\s.*\s(?:[A-Za-z])?[0-9])'
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien. This is great! I just want to pull out the abbreviated state so in line 19 for example instead of `Bloomington, IN 4` I would just want `IN`

Comment: And for others: AB and NY? or AB T2J and NY?

Comment: Correct, Just AB, NY.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take the time to test my pattern. It works for your sample but I don't know if it can work for your real data. I'm really not a regex expert!